# Executing udev rules on boot

Tags: udev

I have National Instruments USB<->GPIB bridge. It is an USB board that need special procedure to became usable. I have linux_gpib package installed that provide two kernel modules: `gpib_common` and `ni_usb_gpib`. Besides, the `gpib_config` tool mast be executed before I can talk to any instrument on the GPIB bus. The trick is that board needs about 2 seconds after it was plugged into USB for internal initialization before `gpib_config` command will take effect. So, I have the following `99-gpib.rules` udev rule that does the job perfect:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="3923", ATTR{idProduct}=="709b", RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/sleep 2; /usr/sbin/gpib_config --minor 0'"

KERNEL=="gpib[0-9]*", MODE="0660", GROUP="gpib"
```

The problem is it only work if I plug the board when host system is up and running. When I reboot with the dongle plugged in I can see both kernel modules loaded, but the board is unusable, meaning that `gpib_config` tool wasn't executed. If I run it by hand it work perfectly.

Since reboot scenario is more real, then plugging it while the system is running, I need the correct way to make udev do this on boot. Sure, I can write some init script that will check if the board is plugged and kernel modules are loaded and run the tool during loading process, but this is udev job cause it something to deal with hardware, I think. Any ideas?

Comment: I am just listing out the possibilities here, `gpib_config` needs `root` privileges.

Comment: Put these commands in a shell script and move it to `/usr/local/bin`. Provide executable permission and update the path in your udev rule

Comment: Well, after some feather investigation I found, that RUN is executed **before** actual module loading. So, at the point `gpib_config` is executed, no modules and no actual devices are available.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in udev that executes RUN stuff **before** corresponding modules loading, therefore `gpib_config` fails to configure board. Workaround is to load modules before udev startup on system boot. Not a real solution, I think.